# "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name" in Program.cs

Tags: c#

```
using API.Infrastructure;
using API.Infrastructure.DataBase;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;

namespace API
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build()
                                  .WithMigratedDatabase<RegistersContext>()
                                  .Run();

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                                                 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseKestrel(options => options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715200))
                                                 .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                                                 {
                                                     logging.ClearProviders();
                                                     logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
                                                 })
                                                 .UseNLog();
    }
}
```

"System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name"" occurs on startup on CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().WithMigratedDatabase().Run().

CreateHostBuilder, Build and WithMigratedDatabase works fine.

Where is the problem here?

Information about current problem and way to solve it

StackTrace:

```
in System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   in System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
   in System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionBuilderHttpExtensions.WithUrl(IHubConnectionBuilder hubConnectionBuilder, String url)
   in TM.Connection.TaskManagerConnection..ctor(HubConnectionBuilder hubconnectionBuilder, IOptions`1 options, ILogger`1 logger)
   in System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   in System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   in System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   in System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   in API.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Repository\Parsers\Parsers\Parsers\Program.cs:line 12
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace for the exception to see where it was thrown.

Comment: I added stack trace and additional info to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionBuilderHttpExtensions.WithUrl(IHubConnectionBuilder hubConnectionBuilder, String url)`

Looks like you are using SignalR but have missed out the url configuration.